# SQL/MySQL - Skip or no select a column from select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to exclude a column from select query. In this approach, i have to mention all the fields name except that i don't want. Is there any other approach?

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, 
     /* ...the list of columns 4-97, not shown in this example... */,
     column_98, column_99
   FROM table
```

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL to achieve this but it seems like overkill to me

Comment: If you only want to return specific columns, then you need to list them. if you want all of them, you can use `*` (just don't use `SELECT *` in a compiled object like a function, view, SP, etc). There is no out of the "* EXCEPT Column` syntax. You *could* use dynamic SQL if it's against one table, but without knowing the RDBMS (you've tagged 2 here), we can't tell you how to achieve that. If you tag the RDBMS you are using, and only that RDBMS, we could show you how.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. As far as I remember, I got this solution from SO years back :)

```
SELECT * INTO #TMP FROM your_table
ALTER TABLE #TMP DROP COLUMN column_name
SELECT * FROM #TMP
--DROP TABLE #TMP WHEN PURPOSE IS DONE
```